# app widget android

Tags: android, android-appwidget, appwidgetprovider

I created an app widget demo, I want to know is: it possible to set it to top or bottom of the home screen?

[image]

When set to bottom, then Android app menu dialer shortcut and contacts cannot be clicked. If screen is empty then it is set to top, but what about bottom?

And if the screen is not empty (suppose there is google search tab bar at top) and I want to display my widget above the Google search bar?

Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do it programmatically.   It is user decision where to put your widget, and whether to put it on screen at all.  You just supply widget size,  and launcher will allow user to put your widget where it does fit.

Comment: Your only change to take influence is to allow user select widget layout at the time he is adding it